# Определение константы MAX для char как 255

Tags: c++, char, max

много где замечал, что размер символьного буфера определяется так:

```
const int bufferSize = 255;  
char buffer[bufferSize+1];
```

зачем прибавлять единицу? ведь char может хранить 256 значений, почему сразу не определить так:

```
const int bufferSize = 256;  
char buffer[bufferSize];
```

тоже самое для символьного массива:

```
const int MAX = 256;  
char array[MAX];
```

Comment: Надо это было спрашивать у тех, кто так объявлял массивы.:)

Comment: :) может так объявляют из-за того, чтобы затем можно было использовать эту же константу, как значение последнего элемента массива? Даже если эта возможность, не будет использована в коде. А не создавать 2 константы, одну для максимального размера массива, а другую для самого верхнего индекса массива. У меня только такое объяснение.

Comment: Быть может, буфер это строка? Длина строки плюс нулевой байт?

Comment: Именно так! Спасибо! если можно удалить комментарий и разместить его в ответах? Я лайкну, когда карма будет больше 15 (уже скоро)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ведь char может хранить 256 значений, почему сразу не определить так:

Размер `char` не имеет никакого отношения к размеру выделяемого буфера - хоть мегабайт :)

Выделяется так для удобства, если вы выделяете `bufSize+1` байт - то можете хранить в нем строку в `bufSize` символов (еще один - для завершающего нулевого символа).

Что касается конкретно 255 - то, как мне кажется, причины тут скорее психологические - типа, круглое (в смысле бинарном :)) число, плюс обычно именно такой размер не может превышать имя файла (например, `_MAX_FNAME` в Windows).